# How to create a 'pop tail' function for a Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, singly-linked-list

Good Evening!

I'm currently attempting to create a custom Stack using a singly linked list for a university assignment.

I created a working pop that removed the mHead element (The beginning of the list) though I am now attempting to modify that function to instead remove the mTail (The most recent node on the list). I created the node, mPrev, to replace the functionality of mNext. The idea being that the current tail be set to NULL and new tail set to mPrev, which would be whatever the second to last node is. 
I believe I will need to set mPrev to the value of the mHead whenever I use push (inserting a node).

Pop and Push are the primary functions in question, most of the other functions can be safely ignored for the most part.

I'm receiving Access Violations whenever I run the code as is. It should go without saying that I am shaky with the content as is, so any clarification or tips would be much appreciated!

```
#include "stack.h"

Stack::Stack(){     //Constructor
   mHead = NULL;
   mTail = NULL;
   mPrev = NULL;
}

Stack::~Stack(){    //Deconstructor
}

/*
Function: int Stack::charConverter(char convertee)

*   Purpose : Convert char to numerical equivilent

*   Pre: A char to convert

*   Post : An integer is returned

****************************************************************/

int Stack::charConverter(char convertee){

   switch (convertee){

   case '1': return 1;
   case '2': return 2;
   case '3': return 3;
   case '4': return 4;
   case '5': return 5;
   case '6': return 6;
   case '7': return 7;
   case '8': return 8;
   default: return 9;

   }

}

/*
Function: bool Stack::checker(char searchKey)

*   Purpose : To determine whether a given character is a usable character (num or operator_

*   Pre: A character

*   Post : A bool is returned indicating whether or not the given is a usable character

****************************************************************/

bool Stack::checker(char searchKey){

   if ((searchKey == '1') || (searchKey == '2') || (searchKey == '3') || (searchKey == '4') || (searchKey == '5')
      || (searchKey == '6') || (searchKey == '7') || (searchKey == '8') || (searchKey == '9') || (searchKey == '+')
      || (searchKey == '-') || (searchKey == '*') || (searchKey == '/') || (searchKey == '^') || (searchKey == '=')){

      return true;

   }
   else {

      return false;

   }

}

/*
Function: void Stack::display()

*   Purpose : To display the entirety of the list

*   Pre: None (Though a populated list wouldn't hurt)

*   Post : The list is displayed

****************************************************************/

void Stack::display(){

   cout << "\n\nThe List: \n";

   Node *tmp = mHead;

   while (tmp != NULL){

      cout << tmp->mData;

      if (tmp->mNext != NULL)

         cout << "";

      tmp = tmp->mNext;

   }

   delete(tmp);

}

/*
Function: bool Stack::push(int data)

*   Purpose : To push a given character/number into the list

*   Pre: A character/number to add and a list to add to

*   Post : A new character/number is added

****************************************************************/

bool Stack::push(int data){

   Node *newNode;

   if (mHead == NULL){

      mHead = new Node(data);   //new case

      if (mHead == NULL)

         return false;

      mTail = mHead;    //add to end of case

   }

   else{

      if (isExist(data))
         return false;

      newNode = new Node(data);
      mTail->mNext = newNode;
      mTail = newNode;

      return true;

   }        //for else

   return true;

}   //either way, it is entered successfully

/*
Function: bool Stack::isExist(int searchKey)

*   Purpose : To determine whether a given character exists within the list

*   Pre: A populated list and character to search for

*   Post : A bool is returned indicating whether or not the given character exists

****************************************************************/

bool Stack::isExist(int searchKey){

   Node *tmp = mHead;

   while (tmp != NULL){

      if (tmp->mData == searchKey)
         return true;

      tmp = tmp->mNext;

   }

   return false;

}

/*
Function: bool Stack::isNumber(char searchKey)

*   Purpose : To determine whether a given character is a number

*   Pre: A character

*   Post : A bool is returned indicating whether or not the given is a number

****************************************************************/

bool Stack::isNumber(char searchKey){

   if ((searchKey == '1') || (searchKey == '2') || (searchKey == '3') || (searchKey == '4') || (searchKey == '5') 
      || (searchKey == '6') || (searchKey == '7') || (searchKey == '8') || (searchKey == '9')){

      return true;

   }
   else {

      return false;

   }

}

/*
Function: bool Stack::operate(int num1, int num2, char function)

*   Purpose : Perform mathematical functions

*   Pre: 2 numbers to operate on and an operator

*   Post : An integer is returned

****************************************************************/

int Stack::operate(int num1, int num2, char function){

   switch (function){

      case '*': return (num1*num2);
      case '-': return (num1-num2);
      case '+': return (num1+num2);
      case '^': return (num1^num2);
      case '/': return (num1/num2);

   }

}

/*
Function: char Stack::pop()

*   Purpose : To pop the top of the list

*   Pre: A list with at least 1 character

*   Post : The list has 1 less character

****************************************************************/

char Stack::pop(){

   Node *tmp;

   char data;       //when nothing to pop, it will return this value

   if (mTail != NULL){

      tmp = mTail;      //tmp pointing at node to be deleted

      if (mHead == mTail){

         mHead = NULL;
         mTail = NULL;

      }

      else{

         mTail = mTail->mPrev;

      }

      tmp->mPrev = NULL;
      data = tmp->mData;
      delete tmp;

   }

   return data;

}

/*
Function: char Stack::returnNumber(char searchKey)

*   Purpose : To recieve a char input and output the corresponding int

*   Pre: A char that has been checked using isNumber()

*   Post : An int is returned

****************************************************************/

int Stack::returnNumber(char searchKey){

   //Before using this function, be sure to make sure the input is a number using isNumber()

   switch (searchKey){

      case '1': return 1;
         break;
      case '2': return 2;
         break;
      case '3': return 3;
         break;
      case '4': return 4;
         break;
      case '5': return 5;
         break;
      case '6': return 6;
         break;
      case '7': return 7;
         break;
      case '8': return 8;
         break;
      default: return 9;

   }

}

/*
Function: int Stack::top()

*   Purpose : To return the value of the top member of the stack

*   Pre: A stack with node(s)

*   Post : An int is returned

****************************************************************/

int Stack::top(){  //Essentiall a get function  

   Node *tmp = mTail;

return tmp->mData;

}

void Stack::userInput(){

   bool validation = false;
   string userInput, junk;
   int lengthCheck = 1;

   while (validation == false){

      cout << "\nEnter your equation in postfix: ";
         getline(cin, userInput);

         for (char & input : userInput)     
         {

            if (((lengthCheck == 1) || (lengthCheck == 2)) && (isNumber(input) == 0)){    //Make sure first character is a number is a number
               cout << ERROR_INVALID_FIRST_LAST << endl;
               break;

            } else if (checker(input) == 0){
                  cout << ERROR_INVALID_INPUT;     //Make sure everything is a valid character
                  break;
            } else {
               push(input);
            }

            lengthCheck++;
         } 
   }

}





#ifndef _STACK_H
#define _STACK_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

const string ERROR_INVALID_INPUT = "\nError: The input you have entered is invalid, remember to use only operators and single digits. ";
const string ERROR_INVALID_FIRST_LAST = "\nError: First and last character must always be a number, and last a '='. ";

class Stack{

private:

   struct Node{
      int mData;
      Node *mNext, *mPrev;      //Node gives int and next pointer

      Node(){       //Default constructor
         mNext = NULL;
         mPrev = NULL;
      }

      Node(int value){
         mData = value;
         mNext = NULL;
      }
   };

   Node *mHead, *mTail, *mPrev;     //Start and end of list

public:

   Stack();

   ~Stack();

   int charConverter(char convertee);

   bool checker(char searchKey);

   void display();

   bool push(int data);

   bool isExist(int searchKey);

   bool isNumber(char searchKey);

   int operate(int num1, int num2, char function);

   char pop();

   int returnNumber(char searchKey);

   int top();

   void userInput();

};

#endif
```

Comment: You should use `atoi` for converting the textual representation of a numeric digit to the internal representation.

Comment: Use the `isdigit` function to verify that a character is a numeric digit.

Comment: In your pop method: look at your main else.  If you get there it means that mtail = null, but you are accessing mTail->mPrev (or null->mPrev) this is what throws the exception.

Comment: If your `Node` objects contain both `mNext` and `mPrev`, you have a doubly-linked list, not a singly-linked list.

Comment: By the way, `num1^num2` is `num1 XOR num2`.  Maybe you want `pow(num1, num2)`?

Comment: Check out this statement for `returnNumber`:  `unsigned int number = searchKey - '0';`

Comment: The mPrev bit appears to be working as if I input a list such as: {1, 2, 3} and then pop, it comes out as {1, 2, mem error}. Paul is correct in that the null-mPrev is the problem, though I don't know how to work around that. It works when swapping all mTail with mHead and mPrev with mNext (that being a traditional pop)

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the newly created node's `mPrev` to the already existing tail node. So, the created node does not have an `mPrev'. So, in the push function, add this:

```
  newNode = new Node(data);
  mTail->mNext = newNode;
  newNode -> mPrev = mTail;
  mTail = newNode;
```